# How to compare two lists by index in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to identify a special type of number. Basically, the previous digit describes the next, e.g. with 22 - there will be two 2s in the number. And there are.

The next number in this sequence is 10123133 (one zero, one two, three ones, three threes).

The problem is when I am iterating through the list using a for loop, it doesn't seem to work.

For example, when i ask the program for the second number in the sequence, it gives me 33 instead of 10123133. (It gives me the correct answer for the first number though, 22.)

```py
inp=int(input("Enter number of digit in sequence"))
i=21
p=0
numcount=0
while True:
    lst=[int(d) for d in str(i)]
    counters=lst[::2]
    nums=lst[1::2]
    if len(lst)%2==0:
        for counter in counters:
            if lst.count(nums[p])==counters[p]:
                p+=1
                if all(elem in counters for elem in nums):
                    numcount+=1
                    if numcount==inp:
                        print(i)
                        break
    i+=1
```

Comment: Again, what is your question?

Comment: @mad_ they want a solution to the described problem, they showed their attempt and said it does not always give the right solution

Comment: exactly i am also not getting anything please tell me what is the input and what you want.

Comment: @Akash_Kumar apologies, I've added it now

Answer (score 0):

> dude it is still difficult to figure out what exactly you want but
>   what I interpreted is you want to count number of frequency in your
>   string which is an integer so i am giving you the code from which you
>   will get a dictionary of number to it's count mapping.

```
a = '10123133'
re = dict(list(map(lambda x : (int(x), a.count(x)), set(a))))
```

> output re  {0: 1, 1: 3, 3: 3, 2: 1} 0 occurred 1 times 3 occurred 3
>   times and so on. if you want to get output in string just remove
>   int(x) type casting what I feel you are facing some problem in
>   iteration because of this code counters=lst[::2] this return you a
>   list with 2 step size from lst e.g  lst = [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 3] 
>   lst[::2] gives you every alternate element because your step size is 2

Comment: Thank you for the solution! However I don't really understand the lambda stuff, I'm new to python.

Comment: also, I put counters=lst[::2] because I wanted every other element of the list

Comment: if that resolve this problem then at least accept the answer it will close it. lambda is just an smaller version of function you can google it for more information

Comment: No I just looked over it and it doesn't solve the problem. Sorry, I don't think I worded the question very well - i don't want a list of the digits in the number

Comment: then just tell me what you exactly want, what is your input and what is your expected output it seems like you want to achieve simple thing but complex logic